# Convert dd/mm/yyyy string to yyyy-dd-mm DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How do I convert 13/05/2019 (dd/mm/yyyy) string to 2019-13-05 (YYYY-dd-mm) *DateTime* Datatype in c#,sql sever Expects YYYY-dd-mm format datatype

```
string dateTime = "05/13/2019";

if (animalAdoption.AdoptionId != 0)
{
    AnimalsAndBirdsAdoption animalsAndBirdsAdoption = new AnimalsAndBirdsAdoption()
    {
        AnimalsAndBirdsId = animalAdoption.AnimalId,
        DonarDetailsId = userId,
        Term = model.Term,
        PeriodOfAdoption = dateTime,
        isActive = true,
        Amount = animalAdoption.amount
    };
    if (context.AnimalsAndBirdsAdoptions.Any(e => e.Id == animalAdoption.AdoptionId))
    {
        context.AnimalsAndBirdsAdoptions.Attach(animalsAndBirdsAdoption);
    }
    else
    {
        context.AnimalsAndBirdsAdoptions.Add(animalsAndBirdsAdoption);
    }
}
```

this out-put I get

Comment: `05/13/2019` as `dd/mm/yyyy`? There is no month 13...

Comment: `05/13/2019` has to be `dd/MM/YYYY`

Comment: If you use an SQL parameter to pass the date then you can use a variable of type DateTime. That is the way it *should* be done.

Comment: @RoadRunner sorry, its 13/05/2019

Comment: @DavidPilkington If i use code like  ```   PeriodOfAdoption = Convert.ToDateTime(model.PeriodOfAdoption), ```  i will get run time error

Comment: Is there a reason you have a `string` value in the first place and not a proper `DateTime` object?

Comment: Are you telling us that your database stores a date in a string field? Then it is time to refactor the database

Comment: @shivu check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string dateTime = "13/05/2019";
var splittedDateTime = dateTime.Split('/');
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(splittedDateTime[2]), int.Parse(splittedDateTime[1]), int.Parse(splittedDateTime[0]));
```

Comment: Cool, please feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Why use `string.Split` instead of using `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: Yes DateTime.ParseExact would be a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply using below example with using your required format:

```
string dateTime = "05/13/2019";

CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;  
// It throws Argument null exception  
DateTime dateTime10 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy/dd/mm", provider);
```

Comment: "mm" means minutes. will not work. try MM instead in "yyyy/dd/MM"

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of PeriodOfAdoption to Type `System.DateTime`

and then you can initialise the property using the DateTime constructor which has many overloads.

If your string format is always in the form yyyy-dd-mm based on: '2019-13-05'
you can extract the year the month and the day, by perhaps using `.Split('-')` string function or if its the format: '2019/13/05' you can split on '/' e.g. `.Split('/')`.

Then you can create your `DateTime` object using the constructor like so (you can view them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8):

**constructor**:

```
public DateTime (int year, int month, int day);
```

**initialisation**:

```
PeriodOfAdoption = new DateTime(2019, 5, 13)
```

so  putting it together:

```
var dateTime = '2019/13/05';
var dateParts = dateTime.Split('/');
PeriodOfAdoption = new DateTime(Int32.parse(dateParts[0]), Int32.parse(dateParts[1]), Int32.parse(dateParts[2]));
```

If you need a `string` in the c# side, this is very simple in C# and there are many examples online

Comment: If i use code like `PeriodOfAdoption = Convert.ToDateTime("05/13/2019")`  i will get run time error. because my *sql datetime* format is 2019-13-05,I'm using jQuery datetime picker.

Comment: but you can use the `DateTime` constructor, I can update my answer to give you an example

Answer (score 0):

To convert a UK date string to a DateTime

```
public DateTime? ToDateTime(string text)
{
    DateTime? returnValue = null;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    if(DateTime.TryParse(text, cultureInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    {
        returnValue = d;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

To convert a DateTime to string yyyy-MM-dd:

```
public string ToBigEndianString(DateTime? date)
{
    string returnValue = null;
    if(date != null)
    {
        returnValue = date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Then you can put them together:

```
public string ToBigEndianString(string ukDate)
{
    DateTime? d = ToDateTime(ukDate);
    return ToBigEndianString(d);
}
```

But you could pass in a DateTime to a SQL stored procedure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8